# Better to convert voltage at each individual component or convert once for the entire system?

Tags: power

My power source is 24v, and each component of the setup wants 5v and a decent number of amps. I know not to convert the same output more times than necessary, and I know not to chain step down converters.

Is there any guideline as to whether it's better to have one large buck converter that can handle the entire current draw of the setup, or keep the voltage at 24v and have small buck converters at each individual component that's needing power?

Say I have 5 long led strips and a controller, if I keep it 24v 5A and just have a small 3-5A converter at each individual strip/the controller, I'm assuming I wouldn't lose as much power as I would with a single 5v 24A power source. The strips would be connected only via data connections and power for each strip would be independent to avoid mixing the slightly different voltage outputs.

Comment: No clear winner without system specific details. If all strips have power feeds from same point them 24A may be OK. If there is substantial transmission distance then wiring losses rapidly make local converters more attractive. You can but well priced 5V high current supplies (Meanwell etc ). Meanwell reliability/quality goodish. Others TBD. |. 5A converters very low cost on ebay/AliExpress. reliability usually OK but some are not unknown to dislike running close to ratings. In either arrangement a fuse blowing crowbar advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear winner without greater system specific details.

If all strips have power feeds from about thesame point them 5V 24A may be OK.
If there is substantial transmission distance then wiring losses rapidly make local converters more attractive.

You can but well priced 5V high current supplies (Meanwell etc ).
Meanwell reliability/quality goodish. Others TBD.

5A converters are available at very low cost on ebay/AliExpress.
Reliability is usually OK as long as device ratings not abused and thermal issues noted, but some are not unknown to dislike running close to ratings.

In either arrangement a fuse blowing crowbar advised.

---

If you are in NZ - I have dozens of good used Meanwell 5V supplies :-).
Otherwise ... .

Comment: So - the biggest notable downside to local converters is the added cost of buying additional parts? vs. power loss & being less safe, for a high current setup.

Comment: unfortunately not in NZ, but appreciate the offer :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree there isn't one answer.

A few more guidelines:

- The closer together the loads are, the less I^2*R penalty from a single converter
- The further apart, the more benefit in distributing higher voltage and converting locally. If one load is far from the others, consider giving it a local regulator even if using a bulk supply for the rest.
- One large converter is probably cheaper, but...
- several small identical ones net you volume discounts. There may be sweet spots like a cheap reliable 3A or 5A module you can use.
- Consider noise immunity and sensitivity. A delicate sensor or 24 bit ADC may benefit from its own supply, which can be kept separate from a noisy main 5V rail.
- Conversely, a separate supply for a motor or a DSP may avoid polluting a large area power bus (improving RF emissions).
- Consider reliability and availability. Fewer parts implies higher reliability, but...
- critical parts may benefit from their own supplies so that e.g. the controller can diagnose errors elsewhere and shut things down or cry for help, even if the main 5V supply is on fire.
- Hot-pluggable or dual redundant modules **should** have their own supply, even if it's a backup against failure of the main (or vice versa)